# Simple way to make python 3.10 code compatible for python 3.9 and below to use match

Tags: python, match, backwards-compatibility, python-3.10

I am looking for a simple way to make my code compatible for both python 3.10 and below.

Toy-Example:

```
class MatchSomething

   # for 3.10
   def match_matcher(self, input=23)
      match input:
         case 23:
            print("TWENTYTHREE")

   # For below 3.10
   def if_matcher(self, input=23)
      if input == 23:
         print("TWENTYTHREE")
```

When I import this class under a python 3.9 environment, I obviously get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" since it does not now the match pattern.

Is there a very simple way to solve this problem like a decorator or so? I was thinking about putting both functions in a separate file and only import the respectively compatible function depending on the python version (see answer from @ErnestBidouille). However this would also not be a very nice solution since it will reduce the readability of the code (the function will have a very crucial role)

Edit: The reason why I would like to use match over if-conditions is to increase performance.

Comment: "Is there a very simple way to solve this problem like a decorator or so?" yes: don't use `match`. That's it. It's new syntax, so it's an issue when parsing the file itself, you can not hand Python 3.9 a file containing a match statement.

Comment: Not really. Pattern matching is much more than matching constants. You can match by type and properties as well.

Comment: Either stick with old syntax without match or drop backwards compatibility. Supporting 2 different versions of the method will cause more problems than benefits, not to mention this isn't really main intended use for match statements.

Comment: You can still do something, to replicate the module for version <=3.9 , and use a conditional import to avoid syntax error ?

Comment: Incidentally with respect to "the function will have a very crucial role" not only does that seem like a good reason not to duplicate it, as of 3.10 your two example produce exactly the same bytecode aside from a few offsets / linenos. As you add more cases, the difference will be that match/case can `DUP` the variable being dispatched on, but if you're at the point where `LOAD_FAST` becomes an issue compared to `DUP`, you're in a bad way. Technically `match` also pessimises th first branch (since it performs extra work)

Comment: Okay yes sticking with if conditions would obviously be the easiest way haha :D This is just a toy example to show what I want to do. I would use the match method to distinctively act on 10 different id numbers and this method will be called very often like 600k times per loop so I actually would hope for a little performance increase when using match... But what is the intended use for match if I may ask?

Answer (score 1):

A bit strange question, but I would do this if it is an absolute necessity.

One file `match_something.py for 3.9 and below:

```py
class MatchSomething:

    # For below 3.10
    def if_matcher(self, input=23):
        if input == 23:
            print("TWENTYTHREE")
```

One file `match_something_10.py for >= 3.10:

```py
class MatchSomething:

   # for 3.10
   def match_matcher(self, input=23):
      match input:
         case 23:
            print("TWENTYTHREE")
```

and one main file which import correct class version:

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
    from match_something_10 import MatchSomething
elif sys.version_info.major >= 3:
    from match_something import MatchSomething
else:
    raise NotImplementedError('Not working with Python 2')

print(MatchSomething)
```

You just can't override a syntax error, since the word `match` doesn't exist

Comment: Well yes that is my current workaround for the problem. I mean it works fine, the only thing is that I would theoretically prefer to have both methods in the same class but I guess that is not possible due to the SyntaxError. I thought maybe someone might have a specific fix of that.